# Attribute value using TBXMLParser

Tags: iphone, tbxml

I have to parse relatively huge amount of XML data, thus I am going for `TBXMLParser`. And I am pretty new to it. Below is the sample XML format.

```
<item>
<title> Test XML</title>
<link>http://www.google.com</link>
<media:content url="http://blog.directorymaximizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/google.jpg" medium="image">
    <media:title type="html”>Google</media:title>
</media:content>

<media:content url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/web-2/256/Google-icon.png" medium="image">
    <media:title type="html”>Google-Png</media:title>
</media:content>

<media:content url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/web-2/256/Google-icon.png" medium="image">
<media:title type="html”>Google-Png</media:title>
</media:content>
</item>


and it goes on...
```

I want to get the value of second url =‘Have to...’.

```
TBXMLElement *iconElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Image" parentElement:element];
strIcon = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"url" forElement:iconElement];
```

This is the code, I tried. Using this, I was able to get the first `url` attribute value. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: what is the parent node of image??

Comment: I believe parent node indicates the first node of each loop. If so, it is `item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of second Node.. based on your  edited sample data..

```
TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourXMLString]];  //replace yuorXMLString with your string
TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

// if root element is valid


if (root != nil) {
    TBXMLElement * element = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:root];

         TBXMLElement *node= [TBXML childElementNamed:@"media:content" parentElement:element];
          TBXMLElement *secondNode= [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"media:content" searchFromElement:node];
        NSLog(@"the second url name is : %@",[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"url" forElement:secondNode]);

}
```

Comment: Hello! How to parse [this](http://pastie.org/6403467) that *MenuCategory* records are in one set of `NSMutableArray` and *MenuItems* records are in one `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
TBXML *tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourXMLString]];  //replace yuorXMLString with your string

    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    // if root element is valid
    if (root!=nil) {

        TBXMLElement * element = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:root];

        while (element != nil) {
TBXMLElement *iconElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Image" parentElement:element];
strIcon = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"url" forElement:iconElement];

    }
}
```

Hope this works??

Comment: Nope. It didn’t work out. It keeps on parsing, not showing any result.. Crashes sometimes..

Comment: Can u provide exact sample data ..i would wanna check out the parsing